# Qt Qml ChartView align to left

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have below ChartView using Qt Quick Qml.

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 10
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 10

    width: parent.width
    height: 100
        
    ChartView {
        id: myChartView
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        // For removing extra padding around chart
        margins { top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0 }
        plotArea: Qt.rect(0, 0, parent.width, parent.height)
        antialiasing: true

        LineSeries {
            id: mySeries
            name: "mySeries"
            axisX: myAxisX
            axisY: myAxisY
            width: 2

            XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
            XYPoint { x: 5; y: 2 }
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: myAxisX
            min: 0
            max: 20
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: myAxisY
            min: 0
            max: 10
        }
    }        
}
```

The issue that I am facing is my chart `0,0` starts from somewhere center of the screen/parent.
If I update the `myAxisX.max` to some 300 or 400 then I see `0,0` getting shifted to left.
But I want to start my chart always from the left-bottom independent of the `myAxisX.max`.

Comment: I ran your code, and the chart behaves properly - (0,0) is always at the bottom left of the parent as expected. As your chart derives its dimensions from the parent, it is possible that the parent is causing this problem instead. You may want to post that code as well, or post a screenshot showing your issue since I cannot replicate.

Comment: @DFaller Thanks for the comment, ChartView is added inside a simple rectangle which is inside a Window. But when I run this code I get the chart 0,0 at the center. I am using Qt5 and Qt Quick 2.0 and QtChart 2.3.